# How to create submenus from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, submenu

I have created menus `"Home""About Us"` on html page, I want submenus of `Home` and `About us` from database by c# code. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a table in the database to store the `MenuItems`. Then Place the ASP.NET `Menu` control in the page:

```
<asp:Menu ID="menuBar" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="100%">
</asp:Menu>
```

And in the code behind:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
//your sql code to fill dt
DataRow[] drowpar = dt.Select("ParentID=" + 0);

foreach (DataRow dr in drowpar)
{
    menuBar.Items.Add(new MenuItem(dr["MenuName"].ToString(), 
            dr["MenuID"].ToString(), "", 
            dr["MenuLocation"].ToString()));
}

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Select("ParentID >" + 0))
{
    MenuItem mnu = new MenuItem(dr["MenuName"].ToString(), 
                   dr["MenuID"].ToString(), 
                   "", dr["MenuLocation"].ToString());
    menuBar.FindItem(dr["ParentID"].ToString()).ChildItems.Add(mnu);
}
```

Read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/354696/Dynamically-populating-menu-items-from-the-databas) article from codeproject may help you.